# How do I display new line characters without parsing them?

Tags: php, character, newline

I have a form that will edit a config file.  In this file is a value that contains the appropriate new line characters (\r\n).  I would like to print this value in a text input field in my form.  However, the PHP script parses the characters as a new line, which is expected.  What function would I use to display \r\n without actually parsing it?

Config File:

```
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://in.mailjet.com';
$config['smtp_port'] = '465';
$config['smtp_user'] = '*****';
$config['smtp_pass'] = '*****';
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
$config['automailer_address'] = "name@domain.com";

<input type="text" name="newline" size="30" class="text-input" value="'.htmlspecialchars_decode($config['newline']).'">
```

Comment: Show some code and the mentioned config file. Your description lacks details.

Comment: i have done as you requested.

Answer (score 0):

By not parsing do you mean not to actually display the new line? Try using single quotes  around the /r/n?

```
$config['newline'] = '\r\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want this for an administrative interface from the looks of things. First of all I fail to see why this should be configurable directly since newlines will never change for you. BUT, if you want it for various display options then do something like this...

```
$config['newline'] = '\r\n';
```

Then when you want to use it you use a comparison...

```
if ($config['newline'] == '\r\n') {
    $newline = "\r\n";
}
else {
    $newline = "<br>";
}
```

Then you just use the newline variable wherever you need it to use the configured newline property.

Comment: Using single quotes prevents it from encoding the literal newline entry into the config.

Comment: Obviously you can add some else if's or a switch statement to give it more variety.